# Scala syntax pattern matching on inner pattern

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching, traits

I need to decompose a case class by an inner object and the cases are becoming extremely long to write . Is there a better way to write this assuming I only case about the first parameter of the inner object of "context" decomposed by its type?

---

**EDIT: Changed the example to reflect the discussion**

```
    // context should be any opaque type that you want returned to you in your result message
  case class PopulateFeedVersionMessage(inoutContext: Any, sectionId : Int, feedId : Int, newVersion : String, oldVersion : String)


  trait PopulateDBReturnableMessage {
    val inputMessage : PopulateFeedVersionMessage
  }

  case class PopulateFeedFileNotExistsError(inputMessage : PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage : String) extends PopulateDBReturnableMessage
  case class PopulateFeedUploadError(inputMessage : PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage : String) extends PopulateDBReturnableMessage
  case class PopulateFeedRuntimeError(inputMessage : PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage : String) extends PopulateDBReturnableMessage

  case class PopulateDBResult(inputMessage: PopulateFeedVersionMessage, localNewDBPath : String, localOldDBPath : String, feedType : DatafeedType) extends PopulateDBReturnableMessage
```

Lets say in a parent actor I do this:

```
childActor ! PopulateFeedVersionMessage(inoutContext = interestingContextObjectForThisParticularMessage,sectionId = 1, feedId = 2, newVersion = "Some new version", oldVersion = "some old version")
```

in the child actor I handle the message and decide to respond with a `PopulateDBReturnableMessage` type (could be a `result` or an `error` type)

```
 // child
override def receive = {

    case message : PopulateFeedVersionMessage => sender ! handle(message)
  }

def handle(message : PopulateFeedVersionMessage) = {
...
// lets say we had an upload error because the disk is full or 401 or server down or what ever we can supply in the error message
  PopulateFeedUploadError(inputMessage = message, errorMessage : "The disk is full")
}
```

Now back to the parent actor:

```
def receive = {
  case MessageType1 => {
    ... deciding what to do...
    ... decided to spawn a child actor with a context of interest...
    childActor ! PopulateFeedVersionMessage(inoutContext = interestingContextObjectForThisParticularMessage,sectionId = 1, feedId = 2, newVersion = "Some new version", oldVersion = "some old version")
  }
  // async handling the return message of the child with the context
  case m : PopulateDBReturnableMessage => m match {
      case PopulateFeedFileNotExistsError(inputMessage: PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage: String) => {
        // need to decompose the inputMessage.context as a inInterestingContextObjectForThisParticularMessage type
      }
      case PopulateFeedUploadError(inputMessage: PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage: String) => {

      }
      case PopulateFeedRuntimeError(inputMessage: PopulateFeedVersionMessage, errorMessage: String) => {
        // need to decompose the inputMessage.context as a inInterestingContextObjectForThisParticularMessage type
      }
      case PopulateDBResult(inputMessage: PopulateFeedVersionMessage, localNewDBPath: String, localOldDBPath: String, feedType: DatafeedType.DatafeedType) => {
        // need to decompose the inputMessage.context as a inInterestingContextObjectForThisParticularMessage type
      }
      case _ =>
    }
}
```

Comment: I would, perhaps if possible, question the design decision. Why is there a context that needs to be `Any`? Looks like a loophole.

Comment: Because it passed as an inout parameter of a akka message that can not be typed

Comment: basically the input message of actor contains a parameter that can be passed back to its sender as an opaque state to identify certain properties of the context it was run in (for instance could be a time/date/ counter/ or other state pertinent to its run )

Comment: and the type fo the inout state could change per certain conditions that could arrise (i.e in some case it might be interesting to pass in a date but in other instance it might be interesting to pass a hash of a certain "thing" that could identify a state)

Comment: I see. Does `foo` care about a specific (repeating) property of these classes, or are they generally different?

Comment: I'll change the example a bit to reflect

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom matcher (e.g. `InoutContext` below) to decompose `PopulateFeedVersionMessage` into just the `inoutContext`:

```
  object InoutContext {
    def unapply(obj: PopulateFeedVersionMessage): Option[Any] = 
      Some(obj.inoutContext)
  }
```

Then, you can pattern match like:

```
 case PopulateFeedFileNotExistsError(
        InoutContext(strCtx: String), 
        errorMessage
      ) => {
   ...
  }
```